# JavaScript to change images

Tags: javascript

I have set of images named as `img1, img2, img3, img4,......., imgx.` So, I want to code a JavaScript to display an image `img1` at `document.onload()` and on first click image to be changed to `img2` next on second click the image to be changed at `img3` and then same to the next image on every `NEXT` button click. In this manner I need even `PREVIOUS` button to go back to the previously viewed images.

How to implement this?

Comment: are the set of images fixed or dynamic?

Comment: Have you written any code for that ? anything tried yet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var currentImage = 1;

window.onload = function() {
    showImage();
};

document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {
    currentImage++;
    showImage();
}

function showImage() {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "img" + currentImage + ".jpg";
}
```

These are the basics and should help you get started. If you need help implementing the rest, ask us what you want to do specificially and what you tried. Hint, you'll need to handle the case where there is no "next" image to show. Do you want it to come back to the beggining or just not work?

Comment: need to add a previous click too and make sure that the function does not go out of range of the images

Comment: @LaurenceBurke I sure as hell won't make it all for him. He's got to learn and try himself.

Comment: Just letting the OP know what else needs to be added. Sorry should have put an @ tag for that

Comment: Ahh. Sorry about the rude retort.

Comment: @Xeon06 - This is enough Xeon06. Thanks! I will code the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var images = new Array("img/image1.jpg", "img/image2.jpg", "img/image3.jpg"); 
var cur_image = 0;

function goNextImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    cur_image++;
    if (cur_image == images.length) {
        cur_image = 0;
    }
    img.src = images[cur_image];
}

</script>

<img src="img/image1.jpg" id="image" onclick="goNextImage()" />
```